# Manipulating a sublist in Python

Tags: python

I have a function `func(L)` that does some update on list `L` (no insertion or deletion of elements, just changing values in elements of `L`). I want to apply it to a sublist of some big list `bigL` selected by a condition:

```
L = [x for x in bigL if cond(x)]
```

so that after `func(L)` is executed, those elements in `bigL` are modified accordingly. In C/C++ I would just create a list of references/pointers to the elements I need, but how to do this in Python where no explicit pointers exist?

Comment: Could you provide a concrete use case? Your question is fuzzy.

Comment: Any new list you create is going to be distinct from the list you started with, even if it contains references to the same objects. Python doesn't really allow this form of low-level access.

Comment: @200_success bigL is list of all orders from an exchange (aka order book), cond(x) specifies if I have traded against order x before in a simulation environment. func(L) subtracts my simulated fills from orders, so the result gives me the order book as if my trades were really executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply collect the list of indices, as follows:

```
L = [(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(bigL) if cond(x)]
indlist,L = zip(*L) # split up index and value lists
# ... modify L ...
for i,x in zip(indlist, L):
    L[i] = x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a single, modified list comprehension with a ternary (`<thing> if <cond> else <other>`):

`[x if cond(x) else func(x) for x in bigL]`.

In my opinion that's more python-esque, but opinions here will vary...just wanted to put it out there.

Comment: From the little information that is given in the question and the comments, `func()` should be able to operate on individual items, and doesn't need to operate on a list. Therefore, this sounds like a good approach.

Comment: func(L) needs to see the whole L before deciding how to update it, but I'll think about fixing this. Otherwise, I agree that's most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question: is the sublist of bigL without gaps? If there are gaps, @nneonneo solution is ok, althoug you'll cycle over `bigL` twice, once to find the indexes and once to replace the values in `bigL`.

But if `L` is a continuous sublist of `bigL` I would modify your `cond` function in returning the first and last index of `bigL`:

```
start, end = cond(bigL)
bigL[start:end] = func(bigL[start:end])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there can be gaps.